# How can I write a program implementing difference equations system with parameter

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

How can I make a program with this dynamical difference equations system

```
P(n + 1) = Pn - 0.1(Qn - 200)
Q(n + 1) = Qn + 0.5(Pn - 50)
```

But in instead of `-0.1` should be `R`, and instead of `0.5` then `–Q`.
It must be modeled with constants R  and  Q, researches the following cases:

when R grows, Q decreases.
when R decreases,Q grows
when both grow
when  R is const Q grows
when Q is const R  grows.

It must be a probram with cycle For. And for each case should be a graphics and table with Pn and Qn.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Your question will seem more attractive to more people if the difference equations were written in *Mathematica* code that people can copy-paste. (You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful)

Comment: I was assuming you know about `RSolve`, but I mention it just in case.

Comment: In order to make sure this isn't a homework problem, please post the *Mathematica* code you have already tried. As it is, the question will likely be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot@ Transpose@ RecurrenceTable[{
  p[n + 1] == p[n] + (r0 + rTan n) (q[n] - 200),
  q[n + 1] == q[n] + (s0 + sTan n) (p[n] - 50),
  p[0] == dp0, 
  q[0] == dq0}, {p, q}, {n, 0, 50}], 
  {dp0, 0, 1}, {dq0, 0, 1}, {r0,  0, 1}, {s0, 0, 1}, {sTan, -1, 1}, {rTan, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]